# JMeter Dynamic JSON list generation

Tags: json, list, jmeter

i'm using the following groovy script :

```
def oldRequest = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())

oldRequest.values().removeAll{it.equals('null')}

oldRequest.advancedFilters.values().removeAll{it.equals('null')}

def newRequest = new groovy.json.JsonOutput().toJson(oldRequest)

sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',new groovy.json.JsonOutput().prettyPrint(newRequest),'')
```

to remove Keys from JSON request where the values are "Null", i also want to include logic to convert below JSON:

```
{
    "sortOrder": "A",
    "sortField": "policyNumber",
    "searchTerritories": [ter1|ter2|ter3],
    "pageNumberRequested": "1",
    "pageCountRequested": "50",
    "policyStatus" : "${ActionStatus}",
    "includeTerm : "null",
    "advancedFilters": {
        "test" : "null",
        "test1" : [A|B],
        "test1" : [C|D|E]}    
}
```

to:

```
{
    "sortOrder": "A",
    "sortField": "policyNumber",
    "searchTerritories": ["ter1","ter2","ter3"],
    "pageNumberRequested": "1",
    "pageCountRequested": "50",
    "policyStatus" : "${ActionStatus}",
    "advancedFilters": {
        "test1" : ["A","B"],
        "test2" : ["C","D","E"]}     
}
```

I want the input JSON values to be converted from [ter1|ter2|ter3] to ["ter1","ter2","ter3"] and [A|B] [C|D|E] converted to ["A","B"] ["C","D","E"], please help me with the groovy script modifications required.

Answer (score 0):

Your source data is not a valid [JSON](http://json.org/), you can check it using i.e. [online JSON validation tool](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

[image]

Therefore unfortunately you will not be able to use [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.0/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html), you will have to treat the source data as normal text and amend it according to your needs using i.e. [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Example code:

```
def oldRequest = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()
log.info('Before: ' + oldRequest)
oldRequest = oldRequest.replaceAll('(\\w+)\\|', '"$1",').replaceAll('(\\w+)\\]', '"$1"]').replaceAll("(?m)^.*null.*(?:\\r?\\n)?","")
def matcher = (oldRequest =~ /test\d+/)
def i = 0
while (matcher.find()) {
    oldRequest = oldRequest.replaceFirst(matcher.group(0), 'test' + ++i)
}
log.info('After: ' + oldRequest)
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', oldRequest, '')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Groovy Goodness: Matchers for Regular Expressions](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-matchers-for-regular.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Thanks for responding.

Comment: Thanks for responding. 
Can you suggest a way to use CSV dataset config for sending dynamic List into HTTP request.
for e.g. sending values ["A", "B"] or ["A","B","C"] into a same key from CSV, 
also i want to use the same CSV file for DB assertion.
so the same CSV file should be input for HTTP and JDBC request, Please suggest any solution you can think of.